# ExtJs 4.2 - Property Grid with form fields?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm trying to create a property grid, with form fields in the value column. By default when I click on the value, it turns to a text input. But I want it to be always visible as a text field or a combobox or a datepicker etc. I tried using `sourceConfig`, but no luck. How to do it?

Here's some of my code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
    title: 'Details',
    id: 'settings-details',
    source: {
        "Username": "Username", //Need a text input
        "Email": "Email",
        "State": "State"        //Need a combo
    },
    sourceConfig: {
        "Username": {
            editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', { allowBlank: true }),
            displayName: 'Whatever'
        }
    }
}),
```

Comment: Maybe you should try the example from here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-cfg-sourceConfig Haven't used Property grid before, but from what I can see you should use deafault keys in the source object as stated in the example.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-method-setSource

Comment: check this also: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#property-grid

Comment: I have referred the same example, but the problem is that the field is revealed only when I click the row item. I want it to be visible always, as in a form. Should I use something other than a Grid, that looks like a grid?

Comment: Ext.property.Grid extends Ext.grid.Panel so there must be some trick. :) I don't know, maybe try to search answer in Ext.selection.Model

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your combo inside the sourceConfig or using a variable like this:

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        // More states here....
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
   title: 'Details',
   id: 'settings-details',
   width: 300,
   renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   source: {
       Username: "Username", //Need a text input
       Email: "email@domain.com",
       state: "State"        //Need a combo
   },
   sourceConfig: {
       state: {
           editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
              fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
              store: states,
              queryMode: 'local',
              displayField: 'name',
              valueField: 'abbr'
           }),
           displayName: 'State'
        }
    }
});
```

This should set a combo as your state editor...

Comment: I'm using `sourceConfig`, but the field is displayed only when I click on the row. I want it to be always visible.

Comment: Any solution my friend? I want the editor to be visible always, not only on click!

Comment: This component doesnt work that way, if you want a Combobox to be visible all the time, you will need a regular grid with a template column. Or you can set your editor to be enabled with 1 click.